# Is it possible to cache pip downloads in a http cache server?

Tags: linux, python, pip, apt-cacher

I have a virtual linux machine with python2 and pip installed.
I want to save bandwidth by caching pip downloads in a http cache server and
use this cache server in other machines. The functionality that I require is
similar to `apt-cacher-ng` but for python packages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at python docs I could find the following topic: [Package index mirrors and caches](https://packaging.python.org/guides/index-mirrors-and-caches/). And this document lead me to devpi-server:

- [Quickstart: running a pypi mirror on your laptop](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/latest/+d/quickstart-pypimirror.html)

Take a look and see if it works :)